# Centrally manage "Sharepoint Sites" in Office 2010

Tags: office-integration

Is it possible by group policy or other means, to customize the list of "Sharepoint Sites" that the user view on the Office 2010 Open menu? I don't think my users are able to do this on their own...

I have googled but so far no clear answer or paper.

Answer (score 1):

The most common way is to use the Personalization Site Links from within the User Profile Service Application. Once the user has first visited their MySite and set this MySite as the default, the links defined here will be propogated into the SharePoint Sites option in the open and save dialog.

For more information on adding links see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262973.aspx

You should be able to push out the default MySite location to users by using the registry key in the following article: http://paulliebrand.com/2011/09/27/set-as-default-my-site-sharepoint-sites-or-my-sharepoint-sites-missing-in-office-2010-on-sharepoint-2007/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggested methods from Daniel B, you can create the links as simple shortcuts in the "Sharepoint Sites".

You can create links to folders or document sets, in addition to libraries. When I create them, I usually drag a shortcut from the folder/library icon in file explorer. This creates a file (webdav) link instead of the usual internet link, but it seems to work just the same.

These can probably be created and managed centrally, by means of GPO, scripting, copying etc. Although I am not sure if they are resistant to the periodic purging when the "real" links are refreshed.